# Setting up SQL database schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, sqlite

I have a database that needs to meet the following criteria:

- Store various products
- Each product belongs to a specific category
- Needs to have approx. 14 different categories of products
- Each product category has slightly different attributes

Very much like building a PC from scratch. You need a case, hdd, mb, cpu etc. They all have different attributes.

I'm confused as to how many tables I need. If each category has different attributes, do I need a table for each category? I need to access CRUD functions for each category and its associated products. Or do I have a generic products table that covers all the different attributes? That just seems like a lot of redundancy to have a new product form with a slew of null columns.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Could you give a couple examples of categories (with some attributes) and products?  It might help others to get a better grasp of your problem domain.

Comment: Category: electric_motor Attributes: part_number, size, mfg_id, etc... Category: receiver Attributes: part_number, channels, has_gov, has_volt_reg, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to draw it down for yourself that is what helped me out alot at the start alot!

The most common architecture for webshops would be something like `product_categorie>product_type>product>product_variants`

Have a look at:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

on how to use helpers to generate tables and columns, also try rails for zombies wich will go in depth about table relations and comes with a few tasks to complete.

These things are a must when it comes to learning RoR

Have fun learning!

Answer (score 0):

In designing your schema, you need to identify the entities that make up your system.  If the products are all that varied that there would be a great number of mull values in a product table, I would suggest that "product" is likely not an entity--and if it is, it does not have attributes like size, has_gov, etc.  For the two examples you have provided, it seems to me that even though both are sold as "products", they are discrete entities, and you should have separate tables for them.  As a quick sketch, maybe something like this:

```
electric_motor
--------------
id
product_id (FK to product.id)
size
mfg_id

receiver
--------
id
product_id (FK to product.id)
num_channels
has_gov
has_volt_reg

product
-------
id
part_num
description
location
price
```

In short, the attributes that are unique to each member of a category--those that really define it as a separate entity--belong in a table together, and those attributes that all categories members have in common as "products" belong in a separate table.

Comment: I've got it working correctly now. Associations are difficult for a noob like myself to grasp straight away. But these explanations have helped, thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  You might want to accept one of these answers to let others with a similar question know what helped.